# Can a symptomatic, recent recipient of live attenuated dengue vaccine Qdenga transfer the virus to mosquitoes if bitten?

Tags: mosquitoes, malaria, vaccine, vector

Can a symptomatic, recent recipient of live attenuated dengue vaccine [QDENGA](https://www.takeda.com/newsroom/newsreleases/2022/takedas-qdenga-dengue-tetravalent-vaccine-live-attenuated-approved-for-use-in-european-union/) transfer the virus to mosquitoes if bitten?

Comment: When you say "the virus" do you mean the original Dengue virus? Or do you mean the attenuated yellow fever virus with a couple Dengue genes?

Comment: Dengvaxia is the older yellow fever-based vaccine, Qdenga is based on attenuated DENV2.

Comment: @timeskull Ah, thanks for that clarification!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The possibility of mosquitoes becoming infected with vaccine-strain DENV by taking a blood meal from a vaccinated human has been found to be low. Transmission of vaccine-strain DENV to unvaccinated people was found to be "very unlikely", but not ruled out completely.

From [Limited Transmission Potential of Takeda’s Tetravalent Dengue Vaccine Candidate by Aedes albopictus](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5817759/):

> It is critical that live-attenuated dengue vaccine viruses will not be transmitted by mosquitoes from vaccinees to the unvaccinated population, and part of the vaccine safety evaluation requires confirmation of low mosquito transmission potential.[13–18] To be transmissible by mosquitoes, the virus needs to be able to infect the mosquito midgut (infection), escape the midgut infection barrier, replicate in the salivary glands (dissemination), and be released into the mosquito saliva (transmission).[19] The TDV viruses were previously found to be inefficient at infection, dissemination, and transmission in Aedes aegypti, the primary vector of DENV.

TDV (Tetravalent Dengue Vaccine) refers to QDENGA in the above quote.

QDENGA is attenuated by serial passage through dog kidney cells, so the virus becomes better at infecting and replicating in those cells but worse in human and mosquito cells. The vaccine strains (there are 4 separate vaccine-strain viruses, one for each natural serotype of dengue) are much less effective than wild type at infecting mosquitoes, even for blood with the same concentration of virus particles. Vaccine-strain DENV on average reaches 1000x lower concentrations than wild type, these two effects are cumulative. This study couldn't measure the likelihood of transmission because 0 vaccine-treated mosquitoes (out of 186) developed measurable levels of virus in the salivary glands, which are what can transmit the virus to human hosts.

Comment: I wonder if the levels of virus in mosquitos' salivary glands are sufficient to infect dogs, now that the new strain is more infectious for dogs, and apparently they [can be infected](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5576688/).

Comment: well, the new strain was passaged through dog cells, but that doesn't guarantee it's particularly good at infecting dogs. To give a crude analogy, if you forced humans to adapt to living in water for 6 generations, they still wouldn't be able to compete with fish.